# Problems installing yum

Tags: installation, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux

I did **`make install`** on the yum package downloaded from [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/download/3.2/yum-3.2.25.tar.gz).

After the installation was done, if I do **`yum`** I am getting **`yum: Command not found.`**

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it's install location in your $PATH environment variable? In your `~/.bash_profile` you'll see a line like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

add the directory of the yum binary to the end of this, separating with a colon:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/yum
```

I don't know exactly where you installed it, so modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I don't think so. I have just installed it from where I was downloaded.

Comment: Well to find the directory it's in you can run `find / -type f -name yum`. It will take a while to complete but it will give you the location of the binary if you're unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `whereis yum` which allows you to "locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command".

Also, did you run `make install` as superuser? Maybe your user just doesn't have write access to install `yum` to its default location.